# Use both email and phone number in Account kit together

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, account-kit

I am working with facebook Account Kit. During signup, I want the user to verify both email and phone so they can login with either of them. But currently facebook lets only phone or only email for one user id. Is there a way I can use both for a single user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no way for an email and a phone number to share the same user ID. You would need to handle this yourself by using only one of these values as the user ID, and having an association between these 2 values.